# Jenkins plugin: How to access other descriptor

Tags: plugins, jenkins, jelly

I'm wondering if it is possible to access an other descriptor from a jelly file (global.jelly)?

The only way to fill data into a `textbox`, for example, is to use the `DescriptorImpl`, which is mounted in jelly to descriptor:

`<f:textbox default="${descriptor.getName()}" />`

But do I need data from another plugin? Is it possible to access this data from a jelly file who doesn't belong to this plugin?